# Why are $\text{versin}(x)=1-\cos(x)$, $\text{coversin}(x)=1-\sin(x)$, $\text{vercosin}(x)=1+\cos(x)$ no longer used in maths?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, trigonometry

I was preparing for a calculus exam and I came across the Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities) for all the trigonometric identities. There I came across some terms that I had never seen before. They were:
$\text{versin}(x)=1-\cos(x)$, $\text{coversin}(x)=1-\sin(x)$, $\text{vercosin}(x)=1+\cos(x)$ and other similar ones.

In the article it states that these were historically used but nowadays they have no real use. Why is that?  Why are these not used anymore?

Comment: Could that be a question for https://hsm.stackexchange.com?

Comment: I woul assume it is much simpler to write $1-\cos(x)$ than $\operatorname{versin}(x)$.

Comment: It's not that they're not "used", but that nobody cares to give them special names. For example, $\cos^2(x) = (1+\cos(2x))/2$ and $\sin^2(x) = (1-\cos(2x))/2$, so you *could* write the numerators in these formulas in terms of vercosin and versin, but it's irrelevant. Just write $1 \pm \cos(2x)$ and that's fine. It certainly is *clearer*. Anyway, the more important page about wacky trigonometric functions is https://www.theonion.com/nation-s-math-teachers-introduce-27-new-trig-functions-1819575558.

Comment: Perhaps special tables were initially created for these functions because 100+ years ago there were no calculators, and therefore a need was felt to have a look-up tables of values of $1 \pm \cos(\theta)$ and similar stuff. But with calculators widely available to students for 40+ years, such data is unnecessary to collect in a separate way.

Comment: @KCd Hmmm. That is quite possible. In the article it mentions that these identities were used for sailing and related measurements. I think your second comment touches up on the really nicely.

Comment: In France the functions $\sec x$ and $\csc x$ "do not exist". They are written as $1/\cos x$ and $1/\sin x$.  Perhaps someday in the future the English-speaking world will become as advanced as the French and drop $\sec x$ and $\csc x$ as special named functions.

Comment: @KCd That's interesting. In Germany they also never use $\sec x$ and $\csc x$, instead choosing to use $1/\cos x$ and $1/\sin x$ instead. I guess we are all waiting for the English to catch up with the times!

Comment: Versin, coversin, vercosin, covercosin, etc. were indeed used by navigators to plot their sailing courses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As θ goes to zero, versin(θ) is the difference between two nearly equal quantities, so a user of a trigonometric table for the cosine alone would need a very high accuracy to obtain the versine in order to avoid catastrophic cancellation, making separate tables for the latter convenient.

These days we walk around with devices capable of approximating the versine to a degree of accuracy that would in the past be considered an extraordinary degree of accuracy and capable of looking up tables the size of books for exact results.

That is the practical aspect, the other aspect is that it has fallen out of taste, and there is no accounting for taste so take it as you will.

Answer (score 2):

The versine function is well documented in this Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Versine

> The versine or versed sine is a trigonometric function found in some of the earliest (Vedic Aryabhatia I) trigonometric tables. The versine of an angle is 1 minus its cosine.

It is very likely that people need all sorts of trig functions to write [trigonometric tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_tables) in the old days. But now we have computers.